# How to use \footnotesize on longtable content and keep caption \normalsize?

Tags: captions, fontsize, longtable

This makes `\normalsize`-d caption, but table index stays `\footnotesize`-d. How can I fix that?

```
Text before the long table

{\footnotesize

\begin{longtable}{lll}
<data>
\caption{\normalsize My table caption}
\end{longtable}}

}

Text after the long table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
```

Also, there is no `footnotesize` environment. Only a switch `\footnotesize`. Put the switch in a group.

Comment: Thanks it works for me. `\begin{footnotesize} \end{footnotesize}`
was already in official template for degree, should i report it that it's wrong? However i'll edit question on this while this is not topic.